# How to properly measure process memory usage on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, memory

I want to measure memory usage by processes on Linux, notably Ubuntu 15.04, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly. I want the measurements to correlate with the `free` command, so that the total amount of memory found to be in use corresponds to what `free` reports (sans buffers/cache).

So far, I've written [this Python script](https://github.com/aknuds1/docker-memusage/blob/master/docker-memusage.py), but it isn't in agreement with `free`, as it reports a lower total memory usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import OrderedDict
import os.path
import re


def parse_mem_file(filename):
    data = OrderedDict()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            splittage = line.split(':')
            data[splittage[0]] = splittage[1].strip()
    return data


def get_process_mem_usage():
    re_pid = re.compile(r'^\d+$')
    re_mem = re.compile(r'^(\d+) .+$')
    pid2usage = {}
    for pid in [d for d in os.listdir('/proc') if re_pid.match(d)]:
        fpath = os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'status')
        try:
            data = parse_mem_file(fpath)
        except IOError:
            continue

        try:
            pid2usage[pid] = int(re_mem.match(data['VmHWM']).group(1)) / 1024.
        except KeyError:
            continue

    return OrderedDict(
        sorted(pid2usage.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))


pid2usage = get_process_mem_usage()
total_usage = sum(pid2usage.values())
print('Total memory usage: {:.2f}'.format(total_usage))
for pid, usage in pid2usage.iteritems():
    print('{}: {:.2f} MB'.format(pid, usage))
```

How can I adjust this program to report memory usage that is in accordance with what the `free` program reports?

For context, the problem is that the memory usage on my server is increasing over time until a lot of swap memory is in use and it slows down a great deal as a result. I should like to know the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

`free` on Linux reads `/proc/meminfo` file (see `proc(5)`). You can ensure it by invoking `strace free`, there is not very long output.

P.S. Updated due to your comment.

`free` shows the information about physical memory. It calculates amount of used physical memory as `MemTotal - MemFree`. So we are interested in physical memory used by processes in the system.

First of all, you are using `VmHWM` field of `/proc/<pid>/status` file. From `proc(5)`:

> VmHWM: Peak resident set size ("high water mark").

That is, the maximum amount of physical memory that the given process has used during its lifetime. It's not the current memory usage of the process. If you want to get the current physical memory usage, look at `VmRSS`:

> VmRSS: Resident set size.

The second thing. The file `/proc/<pid>/status` designed to be human-readable. For a programmer it's easier to parse `/proc/<pid>/statm` and get the value in the second column, which is the same as `VmRSS` in `/proc/<pid>/status`.

Now the most important part. As we consider physical memory, we should remember that it is a system-wide thing. Amount of physical memory cannot be calculated as sum of resident set size of all processes in the system for a number of reasons. Firstly, it's not only user-space processes who use physical memory in the system, but also kernel -- all the device drivers, kernel threads and who knows what else. Secondly, processes can share memory between each other.

All in all, `proc(5)` is a very good read.

P.P.S. Regarding:

> For context, the problem is that the memory usage on my server is increasing over time until a lot of swap memory is in use and it slows down a great deal as a result. I should like to know the cause of this.

If you want to diagnose which processes consume all the memory, you can invoke `top` and sort processes by share of physical memory used (type "M").

Comment: But how do I measure memory usage of individual processes so that the total corresponds to free is the question.

Comment: A lot of interesting information there, but it doesn't really bring me any closer to solving my problem. First of all, I would like to write a program that figures out what's stealing memory. Second, the sum of `VmRSS` among running processes is only 128 MB, while `free` shows that about 955 MB RAM and 1045 MB swap are in use.

Comment: When I sort by memory usage in top, it only shows docker and node on top, at 4.9% and 2.5% memory usage respectively. I haven't found anything to indicate why on earth 1 GB of swap would be in use.

Comment: @aknuds1 It might worth asking on superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: I have written [a specific question](http://serverfault.com/questions/748702/docker-using-huge-amount-of-swap-memory-on-ubuntu-15-04-why) about Docker's swap usage on ServerFault, as I was able to find out via `top` that it was using about 780 MB swap.